# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNDateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, react-native-picker

Getting this error when importing:

`import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';`

`import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';`

```
<DropDownPicker
                    zIndex={5000}
                    onOpen={() => setIsVisible(false)}
                    onClose={() => setIsVisible(true)}
                    placeholder="Choose A Location"
                    items={locations}
                    arrowColor='deepskyblue'
                    containerStyle={{ height: 50, marginTop: 6, marginBottom: 14 }}
                    style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                    itemStyle={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}
                    dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                    onChangeItem={item => setLocation(item.label)}
                />
```

```
<DateTimePicker
                       format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                       value={new Date(date)}
                       mode="date"
                       display="spinner"
                       onChange={onChange}
                   />
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error and how to fix it, can someone please help me.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/403#issuecomment-776508049) ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a library conflict, you might be importing 2 same library.